# Missing async methods in servlet api 3.0 jar?

Tags: java, asynchronous, servlet-3.0

I'm developing a servlet 3.0 application that has to process requests asynchronously.

Compilation fails with a

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method startAsync(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
location: interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

message.

I have the following dependency in my **pom.xml** :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Interestingly, the **import javax.servlet.AsyncContext** succeeds. But when I list the methods of **javax.servlet.ServletRequest**, there are none from 3.0 API that deal with asynchronous requests.

```
public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getScheme()
public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getProtocol()
public abstract javax.servlet.ServletInputStream javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getInputStream() throws java.io.IOException
public abstract int javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getContentLength()
public abstract java.lang.Object javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getAttribute(java.lang.String)
public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getContentType()
public abstract java.util.Locale javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getLocale()
public abstract java.util.Enumeration javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getAttributeNames()
public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getCharacterEncoding()
public abstract void javax.servlet.ServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding(java.lang.String) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getParameter(java.lang.String)
public abstract java.util.Enumeration javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getParameterNames()
public abstract java.lang.String[] javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getParameterValues(java.lang.String)
public abstract java.util.Map javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getParameterMap()
public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getServerName()
public abstract int javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getServerPort()
public abstract java.io.BufferedReader javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getReader() throws java.io.IOException
public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()
public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getRemoteHost()
public abstract void javax.servlet.ServletRequest.setAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)
public abstract void javax.servlet.ServletRequest.removeAttribute(java.lang.String)
public abstract java.util.Enumeration javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getLocales()
public abstract boolean javax.servlet.ServletRequest.isSecure()
public abstract javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)
public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getRealPath(java.lang.String)
public abstract int javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getRemotePort()
public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getLocalName()
public abstract java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getLocalAddr()
public abstract int javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getLocalPort()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need this: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1

Comment: Just tried the suggested POM, but still get the same compilation error and the async methods are still missing from the ServletRequest interface. Weird :)

Comment: There might be a problem if you don't remove the other though. Which `Servlet` spec to chose?

Comment: I did remove the previous dependency, and put the suggested one in its place. I need servlet 3.0 because there's no async support in the previous versions.

Comment: Which version of Tomcat or other container are you using?

Comment: I'm just trying to compile the source, haven't got to deploying the WAR yet. I use Tomcat 7.

Comment: Well, this makes no sense. Either the dependency wasn't correctly imported by maven or you're in some kind of jar hell.

Comment: I'll create a new project from scratch. This is really mind boggling. Thanks for the support so far :)

Comment: I created a new project with brand new POM to test the async call and this time the code and the test compiled. I suspect some kind of a package/dependency caching issue with Maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you have somehow "managed" to reference an older `servlet-api` library (probably transitively) that is located in the classpath before the `javaee-web-api`. This means existing classes are fetched from the older `servlet-api`, whereas classes that do not exist in the older spec are loaded from `javaee-web-api`.

You can run `mvn dependency:tree` to look where that outdated library is referenced and then exclude it.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the cause. Surprised that Maven doesn't print out a warning in such a situation.

Comment: IMHO the dependency management in Maven ist just trying to hide the complexity and not actually solve it. As long as the dependency repositories are so badly maintained as they currently are (e.g. in this case, the Servlet API artifact present in different versions with different names/ids), you are bound to run into such problems.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! in my case was from using jcifs, which adds servlet-api 2.4